# How to Convert html table to list using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

**I want to convert the below table to unordered list:**
(This post not giving the exact result: [How to transform HTML table to list with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577669/how-to-transform-html-table-to-list-with-jquery))

**I tried like this:**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var list = $("<ul/>");
            var table  = "div." + 'productTable' + " table";
            $(table).find("tr").each(function() {
            var p = $(this).children().map(function() {
            return "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";
            });

            list.append("<li>" + $.makeArray(p).join("") + "</li>");
            });

            $(table).replaceWith(list);

        });
    </script> 


<div class="productTable">
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><br>
    <a href="">back to shop by all brands</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><a href="">back to "P" brands</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><h1>Paris</h1></td></tr><tr><td valign="top">
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" border="0">
    <tr><td valign="top"><img src="" border="0"></td>
    <td></td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="background: #80826C;color: white;text-align:center;font-weight:bold" width="100%">
    Click a department below to see more products from this brand</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#e7e7e2">
    <tr><td valign="top"><a href="">Sleds, Skates & Toboggans</a></td>
    <td><img src="img/shim.gif" border="0" width="10" height="1"></td></table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td><img src="img/shim.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="background: #80826C;color: white;text-align:center;font-weight:bold" width="100%">A few of our products from this brand</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="img/shim.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><table><tr><td valign="top" align="center" width="155"><a href="">
    <img src="" border="0" alt="Paris Standard Child Back Pad for E-32 Sled" title="Paris Standard Child Back Pad for E-32 Sled"></a><br>
    <a href="">Paris Standard Child Back Pad for E-32 Sled</a><br>
    <img src="img/shim.gif" width="1" height="19" border="0"><strong>Price:</strong> <strong>$29.99</strong></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" width="100%"><tr><td colspan="2"><br><br><a href="">back to "P" brands</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><br><a href="">back to shop by all brands</a>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Further more, why with jQuery? What exactly isn't working with the code you currently have? You also need to post said code in your question.

Comment: I have already this html, but converting this to <ul><li> manually is a time taking process. I am going to convert a site into mobile version.

Comment: Firstly, please, for our sake and those who will maintain your code after you, format the code in a readable way. Secondly, how is the table generated in the first place? Is it generated server-side? If so, change the layout of it there.

Comment: Do you know any jQuery / JavaScript? If not, learn. We're not here to do your work for you, just to help you if you get stuck. There are millions of tutorials on this across the internet. Search Google.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: It is an existing site code written by somebody, so not possible to change the layout now. We just want to convert that site in mobile version.

Comment: Also, why post the code from StackOverflow (which works) but not your own table layout (which doesn't work) ? You'll need to style the list to resemble the table too.

Comment: Please check this link. This example may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229856/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-convert-an-html-table-into-divs

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zUwFw/1/ (it's not pretty, but it works). I think one of your problems is that you have nested table elements, so you need to figure out just how you want to handle that to produce a sensible layout in your result.

Comment: Thanks to all.  It is working, but shows the result 4 times. Why it is like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $('table').each(function () {
                    var list = $("<ul/>");

                    $(this).find("tr").each(function () {
                        var p = $(this).children().map(function () {
                            return "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";
                        });

                        list.append("<li>" + $.makeArray(p).join("") + "</li>");
                    });

                    $(this).replaceWith(list);
                });
            });


//Or 



        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div.productTable table').each(function () {
                var list = $("<ul/>");

                $(this).find("tr").each(function () {
                    var p = $(this).children().map(function () {
                        if ($(this).find('table').length > 0) {
                            var subList = $("<ul/>");

                            var sP = $(this).find('table').children().map(function () {
                                return "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";
                            });

                            subList.append("<li>" + $.makeArray(sP).join("") + "</li>");

                            return $('<div />').append($('<p />').append(subList)).html();
                        }
                        else {
                            return "<p>" + $(this).html() + "</p>";
                        }
                    });

                    list.append("<li>" + $.makeArray(p).join("") + "</li>");
                });

                $(this).replaceWith(list);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Second one is more accurate in my case.